# Adding a cell value to a 1-D array, searching it for multiple unique values

Tags: vba, excel

First: I'm trying to make a search button that if it finds a match between the control value and a value in that specific column, it adds the ID ("bearpass") number to a one-dimensional array. This search can involve multiple criteria from multiple columns (I have one for Bearpass Number, First Name, and Last Name), and any of these values is searchable. Since the array adds the Bearpass number for every hit it finds, there can be multiples of the same ID number in this array. I would like to know how to add on to an array. I've found that I may need `Redim Preserve` in order to keep the values in my array while adding on to the end. Here is my array declaration:

```
Dim matchBearpassNumberArray() As Integer
'redim the array with a value to avoid error from Ubound
' dealing with an un-dimensioned array
ReDim matchBearpassNumberArray(1 To 1) As Integer
```

And here is my code for the control search:

```
If ctrl.Name = "FirstNameTextBox" Then
            'If there is at least one match, increment the total number of search criteria found
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("B:B"), Me.FirstNameTextBox.Value) > 0 Then 'B column contains names
                criteriaNumberMatches = criteriaNumberMatches + 1
                'Begin search loop for FirstName uding DoEvents loop
                rowNumber = 0
                Do
                DoEvents
                'increment row number to check next row
                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
                '1d. look through Bearpass column in that spot
                itemInReview = Sheets("Students").Range("B" & rowNumber)
                'IF it matches, add the BPN of the match to the array.
                    If itemInReview Like ctrl.Value Then
                        'add the value in
                        matchBearpassNumberArray(UBound(matchBearpassNumberArray)) = Sheets("Students).Range("A" & rowNumber) 'A column contains the bearpass number for that value
                        'adjust the size of the array
                        ReDim Preserve matchBearpassNumberArray(1 To (UBound(matchBearpassNumberArray) + 1)) As Integer
                    End If
                'go back up to DoEvents/ end DoEvents loop for FirstName
                Loop Until itemInReview = "" Or IsNull(itemInReview)
            Else: MsgBox "We didn't find any result for the First Name supplied."
            End If
        End If
```

Additionally, should this `matchBearpassNumberArray` get working and adding in all values like it needs, I have another conundrum: I need to be able to search this array and find all instances where there are exactly as many Bearpass Numbers as there are `criteriaNumberMatches`. Since my search block, like the one above, has one for Bearpass Number, First Name, and Last Name, and each block adds the Bearpass number of every match it finds, if I search all of them I will need the ability to count each unique Bearpass Number in the array and if they have as many as the `criteriaNumberMatches` value, then I know I found a match in all the categories.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` is the thing you want. I don't understand the 2nd part of your conundrum though. If I understand correctly, you have a column with IDs, a column with First Names, and a column with Last Names. You also have a form that has 3 corresponding textbox controls to search these 3 columns. This search form is not looking for a match in ALL columns, just a match in at least ONE column, correct? But then after searching "all of them"...(all three columns?)...you want to count each unique ID? It sounds like you may want to use a `Collection` to get the unique items.

Comment: If you type "Sean" in to firstName and "Michael" in lastName: The search function will pull all IDs with firstname "Sean", pull all IDs with last name "Michael" and since it found hits on both, the `searchNumberMatches` would be 2. The search then should check the ID numbers of all the matches in first name, all the matches in last name, and then check to see if there are 2 of any ID number. I figured I could use some sort of count function on the array, like `countIf`  to count the value if there are exactly `searchNumberMatches` of that value, indicting a match on all two criteria.

Comment: I guess then my next question is do you only want to find every `Sean Michael` or every `Sean` AND every `Michael`, but only do something with each `Sean Michael`? If you really only care to find ALL `Sean Michael`s, there's a better way to go about this using a `Collection` object rather than a 1D array.

Comment: The second one, I want to find every `Sean` every `Michael` and (lets say) every `Sophomore` and then display information on every person that matches all three of those. I found information on collection from MS Support, and am attempting to add this in. I am working on adding in the ID Numbers of each `Sean` found, `Michael` found, and `Sophomore` found, then check to see if, within `matchBPNcollection`, there are 3 matches. Which would indicate a match on all criterion. Am I understanding that right?
EDIT: There is probably an simpler way to do a search with collections, and I'm open to it.

Comment: @Tim

Collection declaration

`Dim matchBPNcol As Collection
Set matchBPNcol = New Collection'`

Changed the match > add language in my code

`If itemInReview Like ctrl.Value Then
                            'add to collection
                            matchBPNcol.Add Range("A" & rowNumber)
                        End If`

Answer (score 0):

Changing to a `Collection` Solved my issue.
Also, I populated another worksheet with the ID numbers, and whenever they got a criteria hit, I incremented the cell next to them by 1. In the end, if a ID number had a cell next to it with `.value = criteriaNumberMatches' it was copied into a collection for printing. (still working on that last part)